# How to fix Gradle JVM error in React Native

Tags: java, android, react-native, jvm

Recently, I switched to a new computer. In new computer, I cannot run my React Native project. I tried every solution in web, but nothing worked. The first error i got is this:

`'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.`

For this, i tried many solutions including `compileOptions`, etc. Then, i gave up and switched to **Java 11** because the project was running on Java 11 in my old computer. So, i tried it and here is another error:

```
This project is configured to use an older Gradle JVM that supports up to version 11 
but the current AGP requires a Gradle JVM that supports version 17.
```

I ran out of solutions. What should i do